# How to load multiple child components in angular2 using ngFor?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, dynamic-content

I have created few child components with given names using dynamic Component loader in angular2.
& I am able to load them using their selectors in static way.

for eg.
I can load my component using

`<DYNAMIC-BODY-1>Loading</DYNAMIC-BODY-1>`

But my problem is that these component names are stored in json file.
So I want to read that JSON File & load that component using its variable name.

for eg.
if `uiComponent="DYNAMIC-BODY-1";`
then i should be able to load my component as `<{{uiComponent}}>Loading</{{uiComponent}}>`

here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="#comp of record">        
        <div *ngFor="#pRow of comp.pageObj.pageRows">
            <div *ngFor="#sec of pRow.sections">
                <div *ngFor="#sRow of sec.sectionRows" class="col-md-{{(12/3)}}">
                    <div *ngFor="#srColumn of sRow.secRowColumns">
                       //prints component name i.e. DYNAMIC-BODY-1
                       {{srColumn.uiComponent}} 
                       //Loads the component
                       <DYNAMIC-BODY-1>Loading</DYNAMIC-BODY-1>
                       //what I want to achieve,this does not work
                       <div [innerHTML]="'<' + srColumn.uiComponent+ '></' + srColumn.uiComponent + '>'"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple ways ,but I am not able to get the result.
Is there any way to do that?

```js
import {Component,DynamicComponentLoader,Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault,NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataService } from '../../app/services/data.service';
import {DynamicBody1Component} from './../DYNAMIC-BODY-1/DYNAMIC-BODY-1.component'
import {DynamicBody2Component} from './../DYNAMIC-BODY-2/DYNAMIC-BODY-2.component'
import {FooterComponent} from './../FOOTER/FOOTER.component'
import {HeadingComponent} from './../heading/heading.component'
import {ImageComponent} from './../IMAGE/IMAGE.component'
import {StaticBodyComponent1} from './../STATIC-BODY-1/STATIC-BODY-1.component'
import {StaticBodyComponent2} from './../STATIC-BODY-2/STATIC-BODY-2.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'Parser',
    providers: [DataService],
    templateUrl: 'app/Parser/Parser.component.html',   
    directives: [DynamicBody1Component, DynamicBody2Component, FooterComponent,HeadingComponent,ImageComponent,StaticBodyComponent1,StaticBodyComponent2]
})
export class ParserComponent {
    public record;
    public componentName;
    public absolutePath;    
    constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector,private dataService: DataService) { 
        
    }
    ngOnInit() {        
        this.componentName="Parser";
        this.absolutePath="app/"+this.componentName+"/"+this.componentName+"-MODEL.json";        
        this.dataService.getData(this.absolutePath)
        .subscribe((data:any[]) => {
            this.record = data;
            console.log(this.componentName);
        });   
  }  
  subscribe({
    complete: () => {setTimeOut(() => {
        dcl.loadAsRoot(DynamicBody1Component, '#dynamic-body-1', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(DynamicBody2Component, '#dynamic-body-2', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(FooterComponent, '#footer', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(HeadingComponent, 'heading', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(ImageComponent, '#image', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(StaticBodyComponent1, '#static-body-1', injector);
        dcl.loadAsRoot(StaticBodyComponent2, '#static-body-2', injector); 
    }, 1)});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load components this way

```
<{{uiComponent}}>Loading</{{uiComponent}}>
```

You can't even create dynamic HTML this way.
To create HTML you could

```
<div [innerHTML]="'<' + uiComponent + '></' + uiComponent + '>'"></div>
```

To dynamically add components you can use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)

You also can't have that `dcl.loadAsRoot(...)` code in the constructor.  At this time the dynamically create HTML doesn't exist yet.
You can try to move that code to the

```
subscribe({/* process data - code omitted*/, 
    complete: () => {setTimeOut(() => {
    /* here the DOM should be rendered and dcl... should work */
    }, 1)});
```

to wait until the data arrived and than a bit more to give Angular time to render the DOM.

Comment: I have used dynamic component loader bro,but i cant figure out how to use that inside loop?

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. If you create the HTML this way, you can use the tags as targets for `DynamicComponentLoader`. I'll have to check your DCL code again.

Comment: @gunter..its inserting the tag inside html,but component is not getting rendered :(

Comment: I missed that previously. You can't have that `dcl.loadAsRoot(...)` code in the constructor. At this time the dynamically create HTML doesn't exist yet. You can try to move that code in the `subscribe({..., complete: () => {setTimeOut(() => {...}, 1)}` to wait until the data arrived and than a bit more to give Angular time to render the DOM.

Comment: @gunter..can you update your answer please,so i can refer

Comment: No idea. Can you provide a Plunker?

Comment: no error msg..html console displays <heading></heading> tag inside div tag. but no component is rendered.

Comment: @gunter..any suggestions?

Comment: No, out of ideas. Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: I cant..as code cannot be shared..but its same as I have updated in my answer.@gunter

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer <div [innerHTML]="'<' + uiComponent + '></' + uiComponent + '>'"></div> using angular 4 can we load the component like this

Comment: @Vignesh no. This will never result in a component being instantiated. You can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer By referring the link how can we pass module from html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020164/load-component-dynamically-in-angular-2-using-selector