# Load component dynamically in Angular 2 using selector

Tags: angular

Can we load component dynamically in Angular 2 using it's **selector**?

Lets say we have a component like below,

```
 @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my-component.css']   
 })
 export class MyComponent{
 }
```

Can we load this dynamically into a container using it's selector `my-component`

```
<div #container ></div>

LoadComponent(selector: string){
    // Load using selector?
}
```

There may be a need of exporting components in the NgModule and importing the NgModule where we want to load it.

Not sure on how to achieve this, any pointers in right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38888009/6680611

Comment: @cartant The post is talking about creating a component on the fly, my question is if I have imported a module and want to load the component from that without knowing about which module it belongs to, how to do that. So when we use the component in html it is instantiated by compiler right, so something similar should be there.

Comment: Are you wanting to create a HTML template dynamically? If that's the case, I think the linked answer is relevant. If not, I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Please check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1oVsAjv46UStOZOzQRzu?p=preview.

Comment: @yurzui: Thanks, that is in right direction, however i am looking for a way were I don't need to know the Module type, Is there a way in which we can get all Modules which are already compiled and is available for use dynamically in which we can check if a particular component is available?

Comment: You can experiment like https://plnkr.co/edit/m6UJz6Xb72uzIBiNipDV?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: Seems there are no public methods which can do it today

Comment: @yurzui what If I want to bind the data using Input, like <selector [(data)]="data"></selector>?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan is there a way to load selector dynamically in html

Comment: How can we pass module to loadComponent function from html using webpack

Comment: Why down vote? Is the question not following guideline please let me know what is that who did down vote did not like?. Please maintain integrity at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was able to resolve this using below,

```
constructor(private _compiler: Compiler) {}

loadComponent = (selector: string, module: any): void => {  
  this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module).then(_module => {
    let _componentFactories = _module.componentFactories.filter(_c => {
      // here I am using the selector
      return _c.selector === selector;
    });

    // check if component is available in the module
    if (!!_componentFactories && _componentFactories.length > 0) {
       self.testComponentContainer.clear();
       self.testComponentContainer.createComponent(_componentFactories[0]).instance;                    
    }
  });
}
```

Hope it helps someone.. !!!

Comment: can we load the selector dynamically in html like this?<span *ngFor="let item of module">
<{{item.name}}><{{'/'+item.name}}>
</span>

Comment: Why downvote? this was solution for my question and I have accepted it, if you have another question or does not resolve your issue, you should write your own question.

Comment: Please maintain integrity at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried your sample but the loop is not returning it's looping continuously i don't know what is the problem

Comment: @Vignesh, can you create a Plunker for your issue?

Comment: here is my updated Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/dGFtXTz9KMQicXjuB8R5

Comment: Hi @MadhuRanjan I am trying to implement it but its being difficult to understand solution from your code, can you please provide any working code example? It will be really helpful to understand what is `this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)` and how it works.

Comment: also can you please let me know what is `self`?

Answer (score 1):

suppose your index.html has . 
then in your .ts or js file, when condition ready, do this:
var div = document.getElementById('container');

```
    div.innerHTML = "<my-component></my-component>"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can load any component dynamically using ComponentResolver.
Add following html node into parent template

```
<div #node></div>
```

And your component will look like

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ComponentFactory, ComponentResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent} from 'components/my.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
template: `<h2>Home</h2>
    <div #node></div>
 `
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild("node", { read: ViewContainerRef }) nodeView;
instance: MyComponent
constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentResolver) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(MyComponent)
        .then((factory: ComponentFactory<MyComponent>) => {
             this.instance = this.nodeView.createComponent(factory);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying,but the question is on how to load component using it's selector not using it's instance.

Comment: `ComponentResolver` no longer exists in Angular 2 (it didn't when you posted this).