# How can we access the component module in HTML?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack-2, typescript2.2

Can we load a component dynamically in Angular using its selector? I need to access component module from HTML

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
}


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my-component.css']   
 })
 export class MyComponent{

loadComponent = (selector: string, module: any): void => {
        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module).then(_module => {
            let _componentFactories = _module.componentFactories.filter(_c => {
                // here I am using the selector
                return _c.selector === selector.toLocaleLowerCase();
            });

        });
    }
 }
```

HTML

```
{{loadComponent('dashboard',moduleId)}}
```

I have followed [Load component dynamically in Angular 2 using selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020164/load-component-dynamically-in-angular-2-using-selector/44075114#44075114), which throws the below error:

```
No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
```

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020164/load-component-dynamically-in-angular-2-using-selector/44075114#44075114

Comment: there is no plunker there

Comment: I has referred the link for  dynamic selector loading

Comment: How can i access the module 'moduleId: module.id.toString()' from the component. Thanks in advance

Comment: your example is incomplete I can't understand what you're doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144984/discussion-between-vignesh-and-maximus).

Comment: Can we load expression value in  *ngComponentOutlet like this:<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item.detailName"></ng-container>